# Cancel a socket poll operation

Tags: c++, linux, macos, sockets

On my journey to get a Software running under Windows and Linux, I had to rewrite the socket layer. On Windows I changed from select to WSAPoll and use a WSAWaitForMultipleEvents before including a standard event to cancel the operation before timeout when necessary. As I have to handle more than 1024 in and out sockets, I have to change from select to poll on linux to. Is there any way to cancel the wait on poll under linux. I have to add remoe connections, which will be slowed down by the wait timeout by the poll.

Comment: on a side note, `boost::asio` isn't good enough?

Comment: @Nim For several reasons I stopped using boost in my projects. Here only two. The official documentation is a joke. Vital behavior is not explained. In 1.52 boost::asio has a known bug, where an connect and a immediately close event is triggered if a host port is not open (host denies) with no chance to distinguish it from a correct connect socket. I moved on to C++11 and try to left behind the whole boost thing, especially boost::asio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pseudo internal event using `pipe()` and add the read side of this to the `poll()` list, making it the first event.

When you want to cancel the poll write a character to the pipe and `poll()` will return.  You will know it's an internal event as it will have index 0.

You can even make this a crude messaging system by passing different values down the pipe.

You can do the same this with your Windows code using a manual event.

See this [`IoEvent`](https://github.com/trojanfoe/ChessCore/blob/master/include/ChessCore/IoEvent.h) class that does just that.

Comment: I read that before, unable to believe this is the best practice way. I guess I head to read the value from the pipe to avoid running in a big "event" buffer. Do you have a sample or link at hand?

Comment: @MartinSchlott I have never had an issue with this method and I think it's elegant and doesn't rely on forcibly stopping a system call.  It also means you can set the event before the `poll()` has even started.  The code linked above should provide various examples, however they use `IoEvent` and `IoEventWaiter` classes which might abstract the concept too much.

Comment: Uh, I read over the last line of your post first. Thx for the link!